# Symfony3.4 : dynamic registration form

Tags: php, symfony, registration, symfony-3.4

I'm a bit new to Symfony so I quite struggle here on dynamic forms.
I'm trying to save my users in database, and geocode their address on form submission.

This is my user entity :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Veuillez inscrire votre prénom.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max=255,
     *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    protected $firstname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=255,nullable=true)
     */
    protected $lastname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $address;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="zipcode", type="string", length=10, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $zipcode;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $city;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $country;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="latitude", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $latitude;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="longitude", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $longitude;


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->enabled = false;
        $this->roles = array();
        $this->inscriptiondate = new \Datetime();
    }

    /**
     * Set firstname
     *
     * @param String $firstname
     * @return User
     */
    public function setFirstName($firstname)
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastname
     *
     * @return String
     */
    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    /**
     * Set lastname
     *
     * @param String $lastname
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLastName($lastname)
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set address
     *
     * @param string $address
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setAddress($address)
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get address
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    /**
     * Set zipcode
     *
     * @param string $zipcode
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setZipCode($zipcode)
    {
        $this->zipcode = $zipcode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get zipcode
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getZipCode()
    {
        return $this->zipcode;
    }

    /**
     * Set city
     *
     * @param string $city
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get city
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    /**
     * Set country
     *
     * @param string $country
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setCountry($country)
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get country
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCountry()
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    /**
     * Set latitude
     *
     * @param string $lat
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLatitude($latitude)
    {
        $this->latitude = $latitude;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get latitude
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLatitude()
    {
        return $this->latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Set longitude
     *
     * @param string $longitude
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLongitude($longitude)
    {
        $this->longitude = $longitude;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get longitude
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLongitude()
    {
        return $this->longitude;
    }
}
```

This is my registration form :

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Form/RegistrationType.php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\BirthdayType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use UserBundle\Repository\GenderRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder
            ->add('firstname', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'First name'))
            ->add('lastname', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Last name'))
            ->add('address')
            ->add('zipcode')
            ->add('city')
            ->add('country');

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();

                $data = $event->getForm()->getData();

                $address = $data->getAddress();
                $zipcode = $data->getZipCode();
                $city = $data->getCity();
                $country = $data->getCountry();
                $fulladdress = urlencode($address)."+".$zipcode."+".$city."+".$country;
                $geocode = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$fulladdress.'&key=KEY');
                $output = json_decode($geocode);
                $latitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
                $longitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

                dump($fulladdress); // Works fine, I see full address in dump

                $form->add('latitude', HiddenType::class, array('data' => $latitude))
                     ->add('longitude', HiddenType::class, array('data' => $longitude)); // Does not save data in database
            }
        );
    } 

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }
}
```

For the first tests I wrote a static address in **$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event)**, it worked fine so again, geocode looks nice.

When I tried to get the address dynamically from the form inputs and display the form, I got :
**Error: Call to a member function getAddress() on null**

Looks like **$address = $data->getAddress();** returns NULL because the form has not been submitted as we are looking at **FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA**. I tried to play with other events, but cannot make it work.

When I try to put it in **FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT**, form displays fine but on Submit I get :
**Error: Call to a member function getAddress() on array**

When I try to put it in **FormEvents::SUBMIT**, form displays fine, submition is OK, no error, but latitude and longitude columns are NULL in database.

I also tried **$address = $data['address'];** instead of **$address = $data->getAddress();**, but not better.

It's only my second symfony project, so quite not a specialist.
What am I missing ?
Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is there:

```
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $form ->getData();
```

You should load the data from the form.

The error you got for the address don't mean that `GetAddress()` returned `null` but that `$data` is `null` and you can't access members of a `null` variable.

**Edit:**

From the same link that the one in the comment:

```
            // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
            // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
            $sport = $event->getForm()->getData();
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll have a better look at that. Unfortunately I got those 2 lines from [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-submitted-data), so I think I'll have quite a hard time to see where I'm wrong. I'm also a bit lost on which FormEvent I should work on.

Comment: Indeed, it makes sense, thanks, but I tried to change **$data = $form ->getData();** to **$data = $event->getForm()->getData();** or call directly **$address = $event->getForm()->getData()->getAddress();** but it's still NULL, guess I'll have to read the whole doc again quite not getting it.

Comment: Looks like **$form->add(..** does not work whithin **FormEvents::SUBMIT**, as the script returns NULL with a static address, which worked whithin **FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA**.

Comment: I don't have access at my Symfony projects at the moment to help you more now but the problem is at this line, for a reason, getData() return null.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your effort. Maybe I should try something like **setData()** instead of **$form->add(..** ..

Comment: I cannot manage to understand what's wrong here, thanks to your help, I can see that using **$data = $event->getForm()->getData();** in **FormEvents::SUBMIT** shows me the right information if I **dump($fulladdress);**. But it's still not stored in database. I update my code in the first question.

Comment: If I read the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#b-the-formevents-submit-event), I cannot add fields on SUBMIT, it's too late. But the data is NULL till SUBMIT, so that's why I'm stuck.. Again reading it all gets me to a point that on PRE_SUBMIT data is not formalized yet so **$address = $data->getAddress();** cannot work, am I right ?

Comment: Sorry for bothering so much, but this drives me crazy. Running some tests, latest point I can add fields is **FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA** and earliest stage I can get my dynamic data is **FormEvents::SUBMIT**.

Comment: OK, I finally got this !! I stayed in **FormEvents::SUBMIT** and replaced **$form->add('latitude', HiddenType::class, array('data' => $latitude));** with **$data->setLatitude($latitude);**. Don't know if it's the best way but it works, thanks again for your help.